# Heat Transfer between Two Water Layers

Tags: thermodynamics

I try to model a sensible stratified storage tank (a vertical cylinder). By using the multi-node method, the storage tank is split into several segments (along with its height). One of the heat transfer mechanism occurs between the water layers, as shown in the below picture.

It sounds shame to me that I couldn't find out how to formalize the heat transfer between two water layers in thermal contact (no mixing of these layers!). Can you please help me with this?

[image]

Regards.

Comment: Are you familiar with the transient heat conduction equation?

Comment: I cannot figure out how to deal it at all. So please guide me however you like (book suggestion, topic to study,...). Regards.

Comment: Some references: *Transport Phenomena*, Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot;
*Heat Transmission*, McAdams;
*Conduction of Heat in Solids*, Carslaw and Jaeger.

Comment: But what is your question specifically? Do you want to know the equilibrium temperature? Do you want to find the time for the storage tank to have reached this equilibrium temperature?

Comment: Hi @nluigi, it will be a dynamic model (based on assumptions) that I will apply Newton's law of cooling as to the final overall heat transfer (minus or positive to each node); that is the sum of this conductance between fluid layers, heat loss to the ambient etc. But I guess that if you will tell me how to calculate the equilibrium temperature, I can use the calculation procedure in my model (but not sure of).

Comment: @HumanistEngineer - why are you making this dynamic model? What is the aim? You are trying to solve a specific problem, not just setting up a dynamic model for the fun of it...

Comment: @nluigi I will use this storage tank model in a system model of a district heating network. So fast and reasonably reliable storage model is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the literature about multi-node method for stratified storage tanks. So the part for the fluid conductance (between the water layers) is formulated as: 
[image]